# Remove duplicates AND set to a new table

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I'm trying to:

- Query duplicate values from a table
- Inserts in a table, removing all previous values.

Now I'm doing this:

```
var table = dataset.table('CleanTable');

return bigquery
    .startQuery({
            destination: table,
            query: <Query without duplicates>
        }
    )
```

But after that, the destination table doesn't change.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the documentation :P.

To do this, I've to add the property "writeDisposition":

var table = dataset.table('CleanTable');

```
return bigquery
    .startQuery({
            destination: table,
            query: <Query without duplicates>,
            createDisposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            writeDisposition: "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        }
    )
```

This can be found in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query

Comment: CREATE_IF_NEEDED is set by default